# Train softmax layer after adding to intermediate layers of the (pretrained/non-trained) neural network in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I want to train 2 models in keras for cifar10 dataset. First, from scratch (model1) and second by fine-tuning a pre-trained model (model2). I use the following codes to do that:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import load_model

#model 1
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model1.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dropout(0.5))
model1.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
#... training

#model 2
kmodel = load_model('cifar10\\cifar10.h5')
model2=Sequential()
for i in range (len(kmodel.layers)):
    model2.add(kmodel.layers[i])
```

I want to know that:

**In model 1:**

How can I add `softmax` layer (`model1.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))`) after some intermediate layers in order that for each of these new `softmax` layers, I have connection just with previous layer and no connection with next layer?

**In model 2:**

How can I add `softmax` layer to the intermediate layers (i.e. layer #2, #4, #7) which I also have the connections with above condition? (Of course I should freeze all of the `kmodel` layers and just train the new `softmax` layers)

Comment: Why would you want to use softmax after intermediary layers? And what is the input to the following layers then? And what exactly is your (mathematical) motivation for using softmax from different layers?

Comment: @dennlinger Because I want to have a prediction for each of intermediate layers for a specific input. Naturally the output of layer #2 is input of one of the softmax layer, output of layer #4 is input of the other softmax layer and so on. I want to see which layers predict right or from which layer, the prediction will be right.

Comment: So basically you want to split your outputs of layer #2 to serve as 1) the input of layer #3, and 2) the input of a softmax layer at that point?

Comment: @dennlinger Yes, you are right.

Comment: @dennlinger But share is better than split

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by that?

Comment: @dennlinger For example in model 2, layer #2 is 100 neuron and layer #3 is 70 neuron. So I have a 100*70 weight matrix between #2 and #3 which I trained before, and I have 100*10 weight matrix between #2 and softmax layer which I want to train now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation here is the `Sequential()` operator of Keras, which allows you to only linearly stack layers.

In order to circumvent this, we can simply specify the model by a more direct (but uglier) way, [as described here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). It would look something like this for your code:

```
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)

x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)(x)
...
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
```

You can then simply specify your predictions in the intermediary layers as

```
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)

x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)(x)
...

# do the splitting at some random point of your choice
predictions_intermediary = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
# regular next layer
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x) 
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
```

I am sadly not familiar enough with Keras to tell you how it would work for a pretrained model, but I am assuming that you can somehow define the pretrained model similarly, and then specifying trainable layers as in the previous example.

Note that your "sharing vs splitting" question is obsolete here, since creating a different layer/operation will automatically create a different weight matrix, so you do not have to worry about having shared weights here (which in any case could not work, if you had different input dimensions in the next input layer, compared to the softmax input shape).

Comment: Thank you very much, So is the training procedure like the sequential model? Can you add the train procedure example in your code?

Comment: The training procedure should be the same, from what I know about Keras. As I said, I am not really an expert with Keras, so that is as much as I can provide. Furthermore, you have to draw up your own training procedure anyways, since you are essentially trying to do several backwards passes anyways, from what I understand, unless you average over your different softmax layers in the end, and then simply backpropagate "normally".

Comment: OK, If I want to average over my different softmax layers at the end to train normally, how can I do that?

Comment: Now let me test your code, and after that I will accept your answer, thanks again.